# My table seems to be too wide for a page. How do I adjust it

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\caption{Implementation of Volt/VAR Control and CVR.}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Step & Description  & Phase & Benefit \\
\hline \multirow{5}{*}{1} & Capacitors installed on substation & \multirow{5}{*}{Traditional Starting Point} & Power factor penalties are avoided \\ 
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} & Load tap changer on substation transformer & & Substation voltage is periodically adjusted \\ 
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}  & Substation feeder regulators & & Feeder voltage can be adjusted independently \\ 
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} & Fixed and switched feeder capacitors (stand-alone) & & Reduction of line losses (capacity and voltage is improved) \\
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} & Feeder regulators (stand-alone) & & Basic voltage maintenance \\ 
\hline \multirow{2}{*}{2} & VAR optimization with additional fixed/switched capacitors & \multirow{2}{*}{Integrated Volt/VAR Control (IVVC)} & Advanced reduction of line losses and improved voltage/capacity  \\ 
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} & Voltage profile optimization & & Advanced control of voltage profile and system operating efficiency \\
\hline \multirow{3}{*}{3} & Manual control of regulators and capacitors using SCADA & \multirow{3}{*}{Basic CVR} & Reduction of peak demand using CVR \\ 
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} & Line Drop Compensation settings in regulators (not using SCADA) & & Peak demand and energy reduction using CVR \\ 
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} & Local capacitor controls (not using SCADA) & & Peak demand and energy reduction using CVR \\ 
\hline \multirow{2}{*}{4} & Integrated monitoring with Advanced Metering Infrastructure and feeder Distribution Automation equipment & \multirow{2}{*}{Advanced CVR} & Continuous feedback for real-time decision-making \\ 
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} & Dynamic CVR through Distribution Management System or other Distribution Automation control software & & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{Table 2}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Without knowing your font size, page size and margins, how would we know if the table really is too wide?

Comment: You must enable wrapping of columns, with `p{4cm}` column type, for example, instead of `l` (or even better, use the `array` package and its `\newcolumntype` feature

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Without knowledge of some very important parameters, such as the font and font size and the width and height of the text block, it's not possible to give a definitive solution. It's clear, though, that you need to let the material in columns 2, 3, and 4 wrap if you want to have a chance to fit the table in the width of the text block.

The following code uses a modified form of LaTeX's `p` column type for columns 2 thru 4. It also uses a `longtable` environment as the material probably won't fit on one page (unless the text block is quite wide). Note that I've dispensed with all vertical lines and `\cline`-type horizontal lines; the remaining few have been replaced with rule-drawing macros provided by the `booktabs` package. I replaced several `/` ("slash") characters with `\slash` in order to let LaTeX insert a linebreak after the character. (The horizontal line above the table caption is there just to illustrate the width of the text block.)

The following screenshot shows roughly the upper half of the `longtable` that includes the suggestions given above. Incidentally, I couldn't help but get the impression that the ordering of columns 2 and 3 should maybe be reversed. However, this thought is not implemented in the code used here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 
                       \RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}  % default: 6pt

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\hrule  % just to demonstrate width of text block

\begin{longtable}{@{} l
     P{0.32\textwidth}
     P{0.23\textwidth}
     P{0.32\textwidth} @{}}

\caption{Implementation of Volt/VAR Control and CVR.} 
\label{Table 2}\\

\toprule
Step & Description  & Phase & Benefit \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{c}{Table \ref{Table 2}, continued}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule
Step & Description  & Phase & Benefit \\
\midrule
\endhead

\addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\small (continued)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

1 & Capacitors installed on substation 
  & Traditional Starting Point 
  & Power factor penalties are avoided \\ 
  & Load tap changer on substation transformer & 
  & Substation voltage is periodically adjusted \\ 
  & Substation feeder regulators & 
  & Feeder voltage can be adjusted independently \\ 
  & Fixed and switched feeder capacitors (stand-alone) & 
  & Reduction of line losses (capacity and voltage is improved) \\
  & Feeder regulators (stand-alone) & 
  & Basic voltage maintenance \\ 
\midrule 
2 & VAR optimization with additional fixed\slash switched capacitors 
  & Integrated Volt\slash VAR Control (IVVC) 
  & Advanced reduction of line losses and improved voltage\slash capacity  \\ 
  & Voltage profile optimization & 
  & Advanced control of voltage profile and system operating efficiency \\
\midrule
3 & Manual control of regulators and capacitors using SCADA 
  & Basic CVR 
  & Reduction of peak demand using CVR \\ 
  & Line Drop Compensation settings in regulators (not using SCADA) & 
  & Peak demand and energy reduction using CVR \\ 
  & Local capacitor controls (not using SCADA) & 
  & Peak demand and energy reduction using CVR \\
\midrule 
4 & Integrated monitoring with Advanced Metering Infrastructure and feeder Distribution Automation equipment 
  & Advanced CVR 
  & Continuous feedback for real-time decision-making \\ 
  & Dynamic CVR through Distribution Management System or other Distribution Automation control software & 
  & \\ 
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might also try 
\maxsizebox{\textwidth}{\textheight}
{
your table
}
, using adjustbox